# Send data back from component in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to filter my list of data but I want to keep my filter layout seperate to avoid having thousand lines of code... How can I send the filter options back to my main view?

I know I can add parameters to the `<Filter />` component, but I need to find a way to send them back to the main screen..

Imagine my `main.js` screen looking like this:

```
<View>
  <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderListItem}></ListView>
  <Filter />
</View>
```

`filter.js` screen:

```
<View>
  <Input>filter text here</Input>
</View>
```

**Note**: this is a minimized version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the concepts from [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html), this is what you should do:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    filter1: '',
    filter2: '',
    // Other stuff
  };

  handleFilter1Change = (filterText) => {
    // Update filter1 and dataSource
  };

  handleFilter2Change = (filterText) => {
    // Update filter2 and dataSource
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderListItem}></ListView>
        <Filter
          filter1Value={this.state.filter1}
          filter2Value={this.state.filter2}
          onFilter1Change={this.handleFilter1Change}
          onFilter2Change={this.handleFilter2Change}  />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Filter = ({ filter1, filter2, onFilter1Change, onFilter2Change }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={filter1}
        onChangeText={onFilter1Change} />
      <TextInput
        value={filter2}
        onChangeText={onFilter2Change} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Essentially, the rule of thumb is to send a parent function down, which the child will call, passing data to it.